# Viewing P4 packet counter

Tags: counter, mininet, p4-lang

I'm new to P4, and I'm trying to understand how packet counters are implemented.

In the [documentation](https://p4.org/p4-spec/docs/PSA-v1.0.0.html#sec-counters), it is quite clear how counters are defined and then incremented. But I cannot see how one would be able to view the counter using the control plane.

I'm using Mininet and the BMV2 software switch - how would I be able to view my counter values?